# PHP username validation against MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Plenty of time, spent, here is where I'm at:

```
    $uname_query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM blog_members WHERE username='".$username."'");         

    if ($uname_query == $username) {
        $error[] = 'Username is already taken';
    }
```

I'm trying to use the SQL query `$uname_query` to pull the `$username` entered in a form, if it exists, then use an `if` statement to display the error, if it exists.

As it is coded right now, I get no error but also no functionality.

What am I missing?

Comment: I wouldn't do a select because that would build a race condition. Better use an unique index on the column username, try an INSERT. If all went well, that's ok. If you get an index violation error, then give your error message.

Comment: @VMai what if he wants to check before the insert is ready?  Like while the user is filling out the signup form?  I don't see any issue with a this select if the username is the primary key or unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a fetch.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($uname_query);
// $row[0] will contain the first column of the first row (username)
if ($row[0] == $username) { }
```

However, you should look at using PDO or MySQLi since the MySQL api is deprecated.  You should also use prepared statements if $username is provided by the user.

In PDO you could do:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT username FROM blog_members WHERE username=?");
$stmt->execute(array($username));
// fetchColumn will return the first column of the first row (username)
if ($stmt->fetchColumn() == $username) { }
```

This protects against SQL injections by providing a prepared statement without $username and binding it in the execute() function.  PDO requires some different setup initially too, but here is a good tutorial: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: The PDO method worked well for me.  My database was setup as $db and used elsewhere in my code, so by changing `$pdo` to `$db` I was able to copy and paste this code with success.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to fetch the data before compare as

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $uname_query);
if($row["username"] == $username){
  $error[] = 'Username is already taken';
}
```

Comment: When I try this I get the following error: `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the data from the query first.

```
$uname_query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM blog_members WHERE username='".$username."'");         
$arr=mysql_fetch_array($uname_query);
if ($arr["username"] == $username) {
  $error[] = 'Username is already taken';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For one, you need to *fetch* it. Use `mysql_fetch_row()`. Secondly, I'm not sure what that `$error[]='string'` business is. Are you trying to use an array?

Although I suggest moving to `mysqli` since `mysql` is deprecated. Also, I hope you sanitized that string well.